# Geometry cirumscribed circle proof

Tags: geometry

Let lines $l$ and $m$ be two lines such that $l \parallel m$. If I draw two transversal lines to lines $l$ and $m$, how do I prove that the circumcircles of the two triangles formed are externally tangent to each other? The two triangles consist of the two transervals and one of the parallel lines.

I don't know where to start. Especially, how do I prove two circles tangent?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the diagram below (click for big version).

[image]

If we take the tangent to the smaller circle at $D$, and let $F$ be any point on this tangent, then by [alternate segment theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/) we know that $$\angle FDC=\angle DEC$$. Similarly, if we let $F'$ be a point on the tangent to the larger circle at $D$, then $$\angle F'DC=\angle DBA$$. But $$\angle DEC=\angle DBA$$ so therefore $DF$ and $DF'$ are the same line; hence since both circles are tangent to the same line at the same point, they are tangent to each other (as their centers both lie on the perpendicular to their common tangent, and the circles are of different sizes).